# Replace substring between two delimiters or until the end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

In a procedure in SQL Server 2008 I need to replace a substring between 2 identifiers. I do not know the complete strings to be replaced, or if the second identifier exists.

If the *terminator* identifier is not present, I would need the end of the string to be considered one. Also, the identifiers could be the same.

```
DECLARE @startIdenfier VARCHAR(10) = 'the'
DECLARE @endIdenfier   VARCHAR(10) = 'the'
DECLARE @newString     VARCHAR(20) = 'new string that'
```

Sample input / output:

'This is **the** *old string that* **the** process needs to be applied on.' ->
'This is **the** *new string that* **the** process needs to be applied on.'

'This is **the** *old string*' ->
'This is **the** *new string that*'

```
SET @endIdenfier = 'I'
```

'This is **the** *old string that* **I** don't like' ->
'This is **the** *new string that* **I** don't like''

It is a generic replace and I havn't been able to find the proper way to do it, since the REPLACE function does not accept indexes.

**EDIT: This community is awesome. I am sorry I cannot select multiple accepted solutions, but I thank you all for your help. I'll try all solutions already posted (besides the already accepted one which I tested) and up-vote individually.**

Comment: You're being reasonably robust in your definition, but you need to be even more robust unfortunately.  For example: What should happen if the startIdentifier is not found, but the endIdentifier is?  What should happen if the endIdentifier occurs Before the startIdentifier?  What should happen if the endIdentifier occurs multiple times after the startIdentifier, etc, etc.  Once that's robustly defined, start using `CHARINDEX()` or similar to find out where the identifiers are, and then use `SUBSTRING()` to start selecting the bits you want to keep.

Comment: Since this is work in progress, the only border case I would cover for the time being is if the endIdentifier is missing. The other edge cases can be ignored

Comment: One important tip: If start and end are the same alway check there's a pair, if there's only 1 or 3 or 11 **the** so something is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--Find the start index plus the length of the string found (plus one for the space)
SET @startIdx = CHARINDEX(@startIdentifier, @initialString, 1) + LEN(@startIdentifier) + 1

--Find the next occurrence of the end identifier (minus one for the space)
SET @endIdx = CHARINDEX(@endIdentifier, @initialString, @startIdx) - 1;

--end not found?
IF @endIdx = -1 SET @endIdx = LEN(@initialString) + 1;

--Use the STUFF function to remove the old chars from endindex-startindex, and insert the new string at the startindex
SET @results = STUFF(@initialString,  @startIdx, @endIdx - @startIdx, @newString)
```

In full:

```
DECLARE @startIdenfier Varchar(10)
SET @startIdenfier = 'the'
DECLARE @endIdenfier Varchar(10)
SET @endIdenfier = 'the'
DECLARE @newString Varchar(100)
SET @newString = 'new string that'

DECLARE @initialString VARCHAR(256) = 'this is the old string that the process needs to be applied on';

DECLARE @startIdx INT;
SET @startIdx = CHARINDEX(@startIdenfier, @initialString, 1) + LEN(@startIdenfier) + 1;

DECLARE @endIdx INT;
SET @endIdx= CHARINDEX(@endIdenfier, @initialString, @startIdx) - 1;
IF @endIdx = -1 SET @endIdx = LEN(@initialString) + 1;

DECLARE @results VARCHAR(256);
SET @results = STUFF(@initialString,  @startIdx, @endIdx - @startIdx, @newString);

SELECT @results
```

Comment: It should maybe be noted that this answer can give unexpected results, because it currently adds 1 to the startIdx and subtracts 1 from endIdx to keep the spaces before and after "the"

Comment: In fairness to me, I *did* say, in the comments that describe the code, "plus one for the space" and "minus one for the space". If putting this code into a production system, retaining the comment to explain the "magic number 1" may be sensible. Alternatively, baking the space into the start/end delimiters would allow you to remove the 1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
DECLARE @initialString   VARCHAR(32) = '1234567890123456789'
DECLARE @startIdentifier VARCHAR(32) = '34'
DECLARE @endIdentifier   VARCHAR(32) = '34'
DECLARE @newString       VARCHAR(32) = 'ABC'


DECLARE @headChars INT = CHARINDEX(@startIdentifier, @initialString, 1)

IF @headChars > 0
  SET @headChars = @headChars + LEN(@startIdentifier) - 1


DECLARE @bodyChars INT = CHARINDEX(@endIdentifier, @initialString, @headChars + 1)

IF @bodyChars > 0
  SET @bodyChars = LEN(@initialString) - @bodyChars + 1


SELECT
  LEFT(@initialString,  @headChars)
  + @newString
  + RIGHT(@initialString, @bodyChars)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8a179d0e63840dfa60905d9951e4b22

For example...

```
'1234567890123456789'
  '34'                => Start @ 1 => Found @  3 => keep chars 1->4
            '34'      => Start @ 5 => Found @ 13 => keep chars 13->end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
/*Declare necessary variables*/
DECLARE @startIndex INT
DECLARE @endIndex INT
DECLARE @startReplace INT
DECLARE @lengthReplace INT
DECLARE @replaceString VARCHAR(500)

/*Get the index of the start/end idenfier*/
SELECT @startIndex = CHARINDEX ( @startIdenfier ,  @originalString)
SELECT @endIndex = CHARINDEX ( @startIdenfier ,  @originalString, @startIndex+1)  

/*In case the end idenfier doesn't exist*/
IF @endIndex = 0
    SET @endIndex = LEN(@originalString) + 1

SET @startReplace = @startIndex + len(@startIdenfier)
SET @lengthReplace = @endIndex - @startReplace

SELECT STUFF(@originalString, @startReplace, @lengthReplace, @newString)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. A +1 here and there needed (to preserve spaces), but the solution is more than appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to incorporate the PATINDEX function and create the pattern by using your start and end identifiers. That will satisfy the condition where both start and end identifiers are present...

```
DECLARE @OldString nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @NewString nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @StartLocation bigint
DECLARE @Pattern nvarchar(200) = '%' + @StartIdentifier + ' % ' + @EndIdentifer + '%'
SELECT @StartLocation = PATINDEX(@Pattern, 'old complete string')
```

If the pattern is located, then you can get the string to be replaced by substringing the 'old complete string', starting at position (@StartLocation + Length of @StartIdentifier + 1). To determine the length for SUBSTRING, you need to locate the position of @EndIdentifier, using CHARINDEX of the old complete string beginning at ( @StartLocation + Length of @StartIdentifier + 1). Subtract ( @StartLocation + Length of StartIdentifier + 1) from result of CHARINDEX.

```
SELECT @OldString = SUBSTRING('complete old string', @StartLocation + LEN(@StartIdentifier) + 1, CHARINDEX(' ' + @EndIdentifier, 'old complete string', @StartLocation + LEN(@StartIdentifier) + 1) - (@StartLocation + LEN(@StartIdentifier) + 1)))
```

You can at this point do a straight forward REPLACE to get the new string.

```
SELECT @NewCompleteString = REPLACE('old complete string', @OldString, @NewString)
```

> "If there is no 'terminator' identifier, I would need the end of the
>   string to be considered one."

If the initial pattern was not located, we fall back to search for the @StartIdentifier only. For this you can reset the pattern to contain the @StartIdentifier only...

```
SELECT @Pattern = '%' + @StartIdentifier + ' %'
SELECT @StartLocation = PATINDEX(@Pattern, 'old complete string')
```

If the pattern is located then you can get the old string to replace by SUBSTRING starting at ( @StartLocation + Length of @StartIdentifier + 1 ), with a length of 'old complete string' length - ( @StartLocation + Length of @StartIdentifier + 1 )...

```
SELECT @OldString = SUBSTRING('old complete string', @StartLocation + LEN(@StartIdentifier) + 1, LEN('old complete string') - (@StartLocation + LEN(@StartIdentifier) + 1))
```

You can then REPLACE...

```
SELECT @NewCompleteString = REPLACE('old complete string', @OldString, @NewString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX`. Figure out:

- the position at which replacement begins (position of `the` + length of `the`)
- the position at which replacement ends (position of `the` starting from see above)

And subtract the positions to calculate the number of characters to replace.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'This is the old string that the process needs to be applied on.'
DECLARE @replace VARCHAR(100) = 'NEW STRING THAT '
DECLARE @delim1 VARCHAR(100) = 'the '
DECLARE @delim2 VARCHAR(100) = 'the '

DECLARE @pos1 INT = CHARINDEX(@delim1, @string) + DATALENGTH(@delim1)
DECLARE @pos2 INT = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delim2, @string, @pos1), 0), DATALENGTH(@string) + 1)

SELECT STUFF(@string, @pos1, @pos2 - @pos1, @replace)

-- "This is the NEW STRING THAT the process needs to be applied on."

SET @delim2 = 'xxx'
SET @pos1 = CHARINDEX(@delim1, @string) + DATALENGTH(@delim1)
SET @pos2 = ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delim2, @string, @pos1), 0), DATALENGTH(@string) + 1)

SELECT STUFF(@string, @pos1, @pos2 - @pos1, @replace)

-- "This is the NEW STRING THAT "
```

Note: spaces should be a part of search delimiters instead of the logic. `the` should not match `them and threfore`.

Comment: Need to also cover the cast where the end identifier is not found *("replace" up to the end of the string)*

Comment: @mat nothing that a bunch of NULLIFs could not fix.